# How to get fragment references for Android FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragmentpageradapter

I'm using a ViewPager with a FragmentPagerAdapter to allow swiping between 2 fragments. I'm not using FragmentStatePagerAdapter because it destroys and recreates new fragment instances when swiping between them, and I don't want operations in one of the Fragments executing more than once). I need a way to get references to the 2 created fragments to pass to the FragmentPagerAdapter, but the following code is producing an error (see below):

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
        initViewPager();
    }

    private void initViewPager() {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragments.add(fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_1));
        fragments.add(fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_2));
        pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(fragManager, fragments);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fragment_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
    ...
    ...
    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Fragment> fragments) {
                super(fragmentManager);
                this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragments.get(position);
        }
        ...
        ...
```

This produces the following error (or similar):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment Fragment1{4169f780 #1 id=0x7f0b0005 android:switcher:2131427331:0}: was 2131427333 now 2131427331
```

Can anybody help me with this?

***Edit***
I've also tried the following, but it instantiates each fragment exactly twice (understandably), which I don't want. Other than that though, it works with this code:

```
private void initViewPager() {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment1.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));
    pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fragment_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}
```

Comment: how are your fragments instantiated? It looks like you are putting them into the view xml which would give them a container already...

Comment: Does it crash on launch, or after paging back and forth?

Comment: @harmanjd the fragments are defined with an xml file inside a LinearLayout along with the associated ViewPager. So the code I'm using is trying to get their references using their XML IDs.

Comment: @anthropomo It crashes on launch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [very clear tutorial with sample code](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/) that I have used to build a viewpager layout.

As @harmanjd seems to suggest, you don't put the fragments in the XML file with the viewpager layout. Define each in its own XML and/or Java class, instantiate those like you have above (use `fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, CustomFragment.class.getName()))` for a custom class), put them in `pagerAdapter` and give that to the `ViewPager`.

You `ViewPager` XML should look something like this (unless it's part of a larger layout besides the fragments):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ViewPager
    android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: On further reflection I think you need to instantiate the fragments the way I show above, rather than the findFragmentById() method. I might be wrong.

Comment: In any case, that's the method I've chosen, and it works great now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah - that is where I was going, but didn't have time for a full answer. One tip I would give here is that in your instantiation code you can check to see if the fragment exists already and use find, else create a new fragment. This is useful when rotating the activity.